# How to get text between special tags using jflex

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, jflex

I have special tag as "{code}". I need to get some text between two of those tags using jflex.

I am trying to use following regex for it

```
CODE_BLOCK= "{code}"(.*?)"{code}"
```

The problem is that it always returns text between only first an last tags. Looks like `?` don't works at all. I need to have an ability to get only

```
{code}abs{code}
```

from

```
{code}abs{code}{code}{code}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different options here:

If the brace bracket (`{`) character doesn't appear in your text, you can go with `{code}([^{]+){code}` as your regex.

If it does, and it's escaped, you can do something like `{code}((?:[^{]|\\{)+){code}`. Replace the `\\` with the appropriate escape character (in this case, I've gone with the usual convention of a literal backslash character).

If it appears between the tags and it's not escaped, you might want to look at writing a proper parser, because regex isn't really cut out for this sort of thing.